# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio not returning more than 10,000 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a simple query like

```
SELECT *
FROM [LyncConversationDetail].[dbo].[MessageDetails] 
WHERE ProjectId = '13'
```

but I am not getting more than 10,000 rows as a result, not sure what am I missing here as I don't have much knowledge in this. Is there any SQL Server setting for max row count? Or is it dependent on something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check how many rows is in Your table.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [LyncConversationDetail].[dbo].[MessageDetails] where ProjectId='13'
```

Comment: it is showing 10,000 but as i understand it should be more

Comment: Try to runt count query without where clause.
It should show more than 10k i think

Comment: Do You have the same porblem in other tables?

Comment: Other tables does not have this much of data
also running query without where clause gives 173690 results, means i am missing something else, may be it is not saving data more than 10k at once in C# MVC

Comment: @user3559462 Are you reporting the results shown to you by SSMS or by C#?

Comment: @underscore_d i have reported ssms results as i understand.

Comment: So if you're still confused, i.e. your question is not answered, I'm not sure why you've marked an answer.